# UFO movie from 60's or 70's Maybe set in Mexico

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw this on US broadcast TV back in the late 60s or early 70s. Set in that time frame. Some kind of flying saucer had landed, possibly in Mexico. Possibly crashed. Scene I particularly remember, alien had trapped a woman,(investigator?) on it's craft. Used a ray-gun type device to begin to disrobe her. Didn't get far before she was rescued. Besides it was TV.

Discharge from the device looked like 'sparkler' fireworks. 
Very short skirt, coordinating jacket.

I suppose it could have been an episode from some series.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are elements here (60s, flying saucer, Mexico) from the film "The Ambushers" with Dean Martin. According to Wikipedia, there is also a scene where the love interest is " stripped of her clothes by way of a magnetic gadget."

Comment: That sounds like it! Thanks! https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/36775-the-ambushers?language=en-US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Handsome Jim for his comment above. I did finally get a chance to watch the movie, and that is the one I was thinking of: [The Ambushers (1967)](https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/36775-the-ambushers?language=en-US)

ADDED: This is technically a Spy movie. With *Dean Martin* playing Agent Matt Helm (he stared in 4 Matt Helm movies)

An American made flying saucer is brought down on its test flight by an unknown enemy. Matt Helm and its former very attractive test pilot, track it down to Central America to find it and discover who brought it down.

No Aliens involved in the movie. As with all 4 Matt Helm movies, just lots of scantly clad women.

The four movies were based some of *Donald Hamilton*'s 27 Matt Helm novels. [The movies are campy and comedic. The novels have a more serious tone.]